# Vulkan: Why are there multiple memories on the same heap with the same property flags?

Tags: memory, vulkan

I have a bug and a more general related question stated in the header.

First to the question: [vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties) delivers a set of heap and memory informations. In my specific case there are two heaps and 11 types of memory. From those, only 4 different combinations of masks and heaps exist. So, there are 7 redundant memory types. **Why are there multiple memories on the same heap with the same property flags?**

In the same section of the spec an example code shows how to find a memory for a resource using `vkGetImageMemoryRequirements`. I use the very same code which gives me two indices to check, out of my 11 memories. Since both do not fulfill the requirements the allocation fails. However, if I set one of the two manually (the one on the correct heap) and ignore the properties, the allocation runs smoothly. To me this seems like a driver¹ bug where the results of `vkGetImageMemoryRequirements` and `vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties` do not match properly. If `vkGetImageMemoryRequirements` would have asked for a different index everything would run without problems.

¹ GTX 980 with Driver Version 382.33

EDIT: As asked for, here are code snippets and results:

The `memoryTypes` returned from `vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties` on my system are:

```
[0] {propertyFlags = 0, heapIndex = 1},
[1] {propertyFlags = 0, heapIndex = 1},
[2] {propertyFlags = 0, heapIndex = 1},
[3] {propertyFlags = 0, heapIndex = 1},
[4] {propertyFlags = 0, heapIndex = 1},
[5] {propertyFlags = 0, heapIndex = 1},
[6] {propertyFlags = 0, heapIndex = 1},
[7] {propertyFlags = 1, heapIndex = 0},
[8] {propertyFlags = 1, heapIndex = 0},
[9] {propertyFlags = 6, heapIndex = 1},
[10] {propertyFlags = 14, heapIndex = 1},
```

The call of `vkGetImageMemoryRequirements` returns 130 for `memoryTypeBits` (i.e. bits 2^1 and 2^7 -> lines with array indices 1 and 7 are checked by the algorithm below).

Finally, we have the code (from the spec) to search for a memory index using the allowed types (the only modifications are the names).

```
uint32_t getMemoryTypeIndex(uint32_t _memoryTypeBits, vk::MemoryPropertyFlags _desiredProperties)
{
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < m_memProps.memoryTypeCount; i++)
    {
        if(_memoryTypeBits & (1 << i))
        {
            if((m_memProps.memoryTypes[i].propertyFlags & _desiredProperties) == _desiredProperties)
                return i;
        }
    }
    return ~0;
}
```

My `desiredProperties` memory flags is VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT == 2. This is only available for memories 9 and 10 which are not in the return result of `vkGetImageMemoryRequirements` but on the same heap as memory 1.

Comment: "*In the same section of the spec an example code*" Could you post that example code? Or better yet, post your modified version of the code, so that we can see *exactly* what you're doing. Also, you should post the results of calling `vkGetImageMemoryRequirements`.

Comment: What are the properties of the image you're trying to create?

Comment: I tried to get a host visible image with linear layout. However, this is not really important to answer the real question: Why does `vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties` return so many redundant memory types? And second: Why can I use a manual chosen index, which bypasses the `getMemoryTypeIndex`, without problems. Apperently, I have a compatible memory - just it is not found by the standard conformal implementation.